# Why does error occur in coded UI application Launch method using startinfor for a bat file

Tags: c#, unit-testing, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to use the application launch method with ProcessStartInfo with no luck. I'm trying to execute a bat file that is a shortcut. Here is what I tried:

```
string myfile = @"\\jcbestbadev01\FSBATest\FSBATest.bat";

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(myfile);
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

ApplicationUnderTest cmdApplication = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(startInfo );
```

That didn't work.

I tried this also:

```
StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(myfile);
string strFileText= SR.ReadToEnd();
SR.Close();
SR.Dispose();

ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
Process process;

processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe ", "/c " + strFileText);
processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
```

That didn't work either. I keep receiving the error:

> The application cannot be started. This could be due to one of the following reasons: 
>   1) Another instance of the application is already running and only one instance can be running at a time.
>   2) The application started another process and has now stopped. You may need to launch the process directly.
>   3) You do not have sufficient privileges for this application.

For my first solution, it kicks it off and still throws errors even though it has already executed and opened the app. The last solution, it throws errors.

Can someone tell me why it throws an error even after executing and running the file?

Comment: What's the reason you don't use the ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(executableLocation); to start your application?

Comment: why use a bat file when running codedui? (the bat file is supposed to open the app that you want to test?), to run bat file u can use the regular Process class and after it has run execute the test.

Comment: Well the application i'm automating is 3rd party vendor application. This application uses a bat file, that have some environmental variables set up in it and you cant run it like a normal exe so you have to run it from the bat file.  If it was an executable i would have no problem using the launch method with exe but since its a bat file i have no way around it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you cant use the the application launch to launch a quick once application using a batch file set up.

I ended up using the the code below with just kicks off the process for that bat file. Hope this helps someone.

```
        string myfile = @"\\jhqfsbadev01\FSBATest\FSBATest.bat";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myfile);
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works for launching and application too. I was launching an application an addition to my application under test and your solution is what I had to do. I still don't understand why ApplicationUnderTest.Launch launches the app but then raises an object reference error but thanks to you I know to use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start instead!